# swift 1.2 if loop to switch statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following If-Statment and I was wondering how this could be achieved with a switch statement?

I am trying to represent an integer value within an array as a string (e.g. 1 == "Jan")

```
func assigningMonthName([Data]) {
    for i in dataset.arrayOfDataStructures {
        if (i.month) == 1 {
            println("Jan")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 2 {
            print("Feb")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 3 {
            print("March")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 4 {
            print("April")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 5 {
            print("May")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 6 {
            print("June")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 7 {
            print("July")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 8 {
            print("August")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 9 {
            print("September")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 10 {
            print("October")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 11 {
            print("November")
        }
        else if (i.month) == 12 {
            print("December")
        }
        else {
            println("Error assigning month name")
        }
    }

}
```

any answers would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just a suggestion, find a way to get month from Int by using `NSDate`. It will make your life easier than use `if else` or `switch case`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use a `switch`, this is essentially just another way to write `if-else` so there is no big improvement to your code:

```
switch i.month {
    case 1:
        print("Jan")
    case 2:
        print("Feb")
    ...
}
```

What about using an array?

```
let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Sept", "October", "November", "December"]
print(monthNames[i.month - 1])
```

The system actually already contains month names, they are even localized:

```
let monthNames = NSDateFormatter().monthSymbols;
print(monthNames[i.month - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes a lot of sense. I have created an empty string within the arrayofdatastructures called 'monthValue', if i wanted to insert the written month. I tried 'i.monthName.insert(monthNames[i.month - 1])' however i got the error 'immutable value of type string only has mutating members named insert'

Comment: @JessMurray That's a bit different question. Probably you want to create a new string (e.g. using `String(format: ...)` and assign that instead of modyfing an already existing string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
switch i.month {
    case 1:
        print("Jan")
    case 2:
        print("Feb")
    ...
    default:
        print("default value")
}
```